# Get users associated with MIN/MAX SUM value

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(totalDuration) AS lowestTotalDuration,
    MAX(totalDuration) AS highestTotalDuration
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        SUM(totalDuration) AS totalDuration
    FROM 
        activity
    WHERE 
        active = :active
    GROUP BY 
        userID
    ) activity
```

however I would also like to get the userID associated with each MIN/MAX result so I know which user has the least/most.

I have tried adding userID in to the query but it only produces the userID of the MAX value.

The DB structure is:

```
userID    totalDuration    active
---------------------------------
1         0.0100           1
1         0.3000           1
2         0.2000           1
2         0.1000           1
3         0.0020           1
```

The query should produce:

```
([lowestTotalDuration] => 0.0020
 [lowestUserID] => 3
 [highestTotalDuration] => 0.3100
 [highestUserID] => 1)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query does not take long to run, just use `union all`:

```
(SELECT userId, SUM(totalDuration) AS totalDuration
 FROM activity
 WHERE active = :active
 GROUP BY userID  
 ORDER BY totalDuration ASC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT userId, SUM(totalDuration) AS totalDuration
 FROM activity
 WHERE active = :active
 GROUP BY userID  
 ORDER BY totalDuration DESC
 LIMIT 1
);
```

If you have larger data, then you can use variables for this purpose:

```
SELECT userId, totalDuration
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             (@min := if(@min = -1 or @min < totalDuration, totalDuration, @min) as minval,
             (@max := if(@max = -1 or @max > totalDuration, totalDuration, @max) as maxval       
      FROM (SELECT userId, SUM(totalDuration) AS totalDuration
            FROM activity
            WHERE active = :active
            GROUP BY userID
           ) a CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @min := -1, @max := -1) params
      ) a
WHERE totalDuration IN (minval, maxval);
```

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit to the question. Best guess, how many records before this could be problematic?

Comment: @puks1978 . . . There is no "problem".  It just takes twice as long to run two queries as one query.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . The first version returns two rows, regardless of whether the totals have duplicates at the extreme.  The second version returns all extreme values.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use mysql since you labelled it with mysql. You can try with a stored procedure (or execute this SQL each time) like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS activity_temp AS (SELECT
                                              SUM(totalDuration) AS totalDuration
                                            FROM
                                              activity
                                            WHERE
                                              active = :active
                                            GROUP BY
                                              userID
);
SELECT
  (@minvalue:=MIN(totalDuration)) AS lowestTotalDuration,
  (@maxvalue:=MAX(totalDuration)) AS highestTotalDuration
FROM activity_temp;
SELECT (@minvalueId:=userID) FROM activity_temp WHERE totalDuration = @minvalue LIMIT 1;
SELECT (@maxvalueId:=userID) FROM activity_temp WHERE totalDuration = @maxvalue LIMIT 1;
SELECT @minvalueId, @minvalue, @maxvalueId, @maxvalue;
```